# Google APIs - YouTube - GuideCategories: list (Android)

Tags: android, youtube, categories

I'm having a problem to retrieve the categories list.
I followed the documentation from:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list

I send a GET request like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=us&key=MY_APP_KEY

I get this response:

```
{ "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "usageLimits",    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."   }  ],  "code": 403,  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." }}
```

Any idea about what is happening?

I've created the key into:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~angular-spider-465/apiui/credential

I have other keys there that I use to upload videos, to use Google Maps, and it works fine.
I'm only having problem to get the categories list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
To get the categories I cant use a Android Key.
I have to use a browser key.
I don`t know why, but it worked!